# Cannot open connection to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, powershell, odbc

I have a few SQL scripts to run against PostgreSQL instance using PowerShell.
I've installed PSQL 9.5 and also the ODBC driver. I also added it to DSN list

Name: PostgreSQL35W
Driver: PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)

In PowerShell I have the next block of code

```
$DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=$dbServer;Port=5432;Uid=$dbUser;Pwd=$dbPass;"
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString;
$DBConn.Open();
$DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();
$DBCmd.CommandText = $script;
$DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
$DBConn.Close();
```

When trying to connect to the PSQL instance, I get an exception with no description:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): ""
At C:\Projects\Scripts\Publish\PublishDB.ps1:34 char:5
+     $DBConn.Open();
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OdbcException
```

Tried to find anything about related issues - no luck.

Comment: If you defined a DSN you should probably use a [DSN connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/odbc-dsn/), otherwise the DSN would be pointless. If you want to use a "regular" [PostgreSQL ODBC connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/): did you define the variables you're using in it? Also, you don't seem to specify the database. And did you try `PostgreSQL UNICODE` instead of `PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)` as the driver?

Comment: I did,  and it said that such driver not installed.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ansgar Wiechers mentioned, DSN name should be used instead of Driver name.
So connection should be as follows:

```
$DBConnectionString = "DSN=PostgreSQL35WServer=$dbServer;Port=5432;Uid=$dbUser;Pwd=$dbPass;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call PSQL on those scripts.

```
& .\\tools\\pgsql\\psql.exe -d ""$connStr"" -f .\\TestData.sql;
```

You can find the psql.exe in your PgSql's installation directory.